# Wordpress shortcode doesn't render

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I created my first custom shortcode in my theme, adding the following lines in functions.php

```
function ec_toggle_content($atts, $content = null){

   $togtit='Title test';

   extract(shortcode_atts(array('togtit'=> ''), $atts));

   $output .= '<h4 class="toggletrg">'.$title.' <i class="fa fa-plus right toggleicon"></i><i class="fa fa-minus right toggleicon hidden"></i></h4>';
   $output .= '<div class="togglecont">';
   $output .= do_shortcode($content);
   $output .= '</div>';
   return $output;

   add_shortcode('toggle', 'ec_toggle_content');
}
```

and when I edit one of my posts adding the shortcode i.e.

```
[toggle togtit="comn pleas work"]bla bla bla text[/toggle]
```

It just renders as plain text... (for reference, http://ipfcommunity.wdemo.it/aggiornamenti/news/respirare-sottacqua-piccoli-esercizi-sopravvivenza-spirituale/)

I really can't figure out how to make it work, I read that the most common problem could be that I don't render using get_content() to retrieve the post content, but that's what I do so I can't find any further advice.

Comment: ehm, are you sure `add_shortcode('toggle', 'ec_toggle_content')` is supposed to be INSIDE the function AND after a return statement ?

Comment: I followed this guide http://mosaikweb.com/toggle-plus-shortcode, it's the first time I find myself templating a shortcode

Comment: @FMashiro I followed your hint to make it work, if you wanna post an answer I'll be glad to mark it as correct. Thanks.

Comment: It's fine, mark your own as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

The following guide was misleading [mosaikweb.com/toggle-plus-shortcode](http://mosaikweb.com/toggle-plus-shortcode)

Basically as hinted by FMashiro, i moved

```
add_shortcode('toggle', 'ec_toggle_content');
```

at the top of my sample code, the working result is

```
add_shortcode('toggle', 'ec_toggle_content');

function ec_toggle_content($atts, $content = null){

   $togtit='Title test';

   extract(shortcode_atts(array('togtit'=> ''), $atts));

   $output .= '<h4 class="toggletrg">'.$title.' <i class="fa fa-plus right toggleicon"></i><i class="fa fa-minus right toggleicon hidden"></i></h4>';
   $output .= '<div class="togglecont">';
   $output .= do_shortcode($content);
   $output .= '</div>';
   return $output;

}
```